# Different Basis Matrix Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I need I little help with this one:

$$\texttt{let } T : R^{3} \rightarrow   R^{2} \texttt{ be the linear transformation } T(1,0,0) = (2,3)$$

Then,

Let $α = ((1, 1, 0),(3, 1, -1),(2, 0, 0))$ be a basis of $R^{3}$

let $β = ((1, 1),(1, 0))$ be a basis of $R^{2}$

To find $T_{\beta \leftarrow \alpha }$ would it be enough if we could do it normally (as it would be an $R^{3}$->$R^{2}$ base)?

What would be the way to find this matrix?

Comment: Welcome! You need to determine the coordinates in basis $\beta$ of eaxh vector in basis $\alpha$, that's all.

Comment: $T(1,1) = a(1,1,0)+b(3,1,-1)+c(2,0,0), $
|then,
$a=1,b=0,c=0:(1,0,0)$

For each element in β ?

Comment: You're taking things the opposite way: $T$ maps $\Bbb R^{\color{red}3}$ to $\Bbb R^{\color{red}2}$.

Comment: Is $T(1,0,0)=(2,3)$ the only information given?

Comment: There is also this information: $kernel(T) = {(x, y, z) \epsilon R^{3}| x-y+2z = 0}$ - however, I does think it is usefull information

Comment: I could just do the oposit them ? $T(1,1,0) = a(1,1)+b(1,0)$ for each element in α

Comment: The kernel is very useful information, because it tells you where the first two basis vectors in $\alpha$ map to.

Comment: I think the simplest is to determine the matrix of $T$ w.r.t.  standard bases, and then use the change of basis matrices for both $\Bbb R^3$ and $\Bbb R^2$.